# What's the meaning of "there's no stinkin' way" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-meaning

When I started explaining the project’s work scope to people in the school, I learned quickly that most believed the technology classes would be my biggest challenge. One special education teacher’s comments captured the opinion I heard again and again:

> "**There’s no stinkin’ way** you’re going to get the shop teachers to work with you on this."

What's the meaning of "there's no stinkin' way"?

Comment: It's an idiom in the US which may have some basis in historical fact but has long been disconnected from its origins, and it simply means "There's no possible way".  (Though you can replace "possible" with your choice of expletives, "stinkin'" being one of the tamer ones.)

Comment: *Stinkin'* just provides emphasis. It essentially means *there's [absolutely] no way*.

Comment: Probably the most famous instance of "stinking" used as an intensifier (and presumably as a euphemism) is [this one from _The Treasure of the Sierra Madre_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsdZKCh6RsU) (released in 1948).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's an idiom in the US which may have some basis in historical fact but has long been disconnected from its origins, and it simply means "There's no possible way". (Though you can replace "possible" with your choice of expletives, "stinkin'" being one of the tamer ones.) – [Hot Licks](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/70861/hot-licks)

> Stinkin' just provides emphasis. It essentially means *there's [absolutely] no way.* – [Jason Bassford](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/291924/jason-bassford)

Answer (score 0):

It is an idiomatic usage of ***[stinking](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stinking)*** (adverb) to add emphasis to the the idea you want to express:

> to an extreme degree
>
> - got stinking drunk

(M-W)

As general intensifier, a euphemism  for damned, fucking etc, its usage dates back to the beginning of the 20th century according to [Green’s Dictionary of Slang:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/oy4hfly)

> 1908  [UK]    A.N. Lyons Arthur’s 61: *Well, I knowed ’im for one o’ them furrin-born beggars be ’is stinkin’*

Answer (score 0):

*Stinkin'* is a common euphemism for a stronger word which starts with F.  I learned this from having a conversation with a police officer.  He had trained himself to use *stinkin'* instead of the F version.